# The mechanics of Aspects on weapons/armor?

Tags: weapons, fate, fate-core, armor, aspects

Fate Core suggests one way to differentiate weapons and armor is by giving each one an Aspect. Daggers could be **Quick**, for instance, and maces could be **Armor Piercing**. I really like this idea. My question is, *how would this actually work mechanically?* I'm trying to picture how this would tie into "Creating an Advantage" or how it would modify attack rolls or shifts.

A few examples to help fuel thinking caps:

- **Quick** Dagger vs. **Heavy** Greatsword?
- **Long** Spear vs. **Balanced** Longsword?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would simply give you excuses for **invokes** and **compels**, based on the aspect text. Nothing less, nothing more.

> *— Wesroth attacks Quadron using his longsword, with Fighting 3*
>
> — Ok but Quadron has a **Long Spear**, here's a compel for you, this fate point says Wesroth spends this exchange trying to close in with Quadron, struggling to find an opening.
>
> *— Good call, but no, I refuse your compel. Here's a fate point, Wesroth does manage to attack despite the **long spear***
>
> **Wesroth:Attack: [Roll + + - ·] + [Fighting 3] = +4(Great)**
>
> **Quadron:Defend: [Roll + - · ·] + [Fighting 2] = +2(Fair)**
>
> — Whoops, that's physical stress box #2 for me …err… Quadron. Fortunately Quadron can take it and live.
>
> *— Not so fast, Wesroth has a **Balanced longsword**, and I invoke it. He feints an attack but flips the sword and uses the pommel to push Quadron's spear aside, easily getting inside his guard. That brings my roll into a fantastic +6. I guess that's a #4 stress box, which Quadron doesn't have*
>
> — Oh cr*p! …

… and it goes on like this

Comment: Would these invokes and compels be free (never, once, or indefinitely)?

Comment: No, they are subject to the same rules as any other aspect. Use fate points to compel or invoke, unless you just created them, in which case, you can invoke once for free but compels always need a fate point